# Should I disable the core content translation module in favor of entity translation?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Developing a multilingual site in the autumn of Drupal 7, I am inclined to use [entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) all the way.

Drupal core comes with [content translation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation). If I have both enabled, I am having a confusing user experience while editing content. I disabled content translations (and some modules that required it), and entity translation still seems to work and everything makes more sense. So tempted to keep it that way.

However .. I just disabled a core module. Is that ok?

Comment: just got a tumbleweed badge. crickets ... nobody ?

Comment: Good question. There is quite a lot of modules and configuration used for internationalization and it can become difficult to understand which module do what exactly. Thought, i'm pretty confident that you can disable content translation as it is not a required module for entity translation and although it's a core module, it's not a required one.